# QT - QGraphicsScene doesn't show properly (z-buffer?)

Tags: c++, qt

This is my simple code for generating chessboard. First are added rects acting like place for figure. Next, QPixmap, containing png of figure is displayed over. I don't see some figures, because they are under that rects. If i put into comment lines where i am adding rect (scene->addRect...) it looks fine. Why? I am painting in order in wich items should be displayed.

```
for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {

            if ((row + column) % 2) {
                scene->addRect(row * 50, column * 50, 50, 50, greyPen, greyBrush);
            }
            else {
                scene->addRect(row * 50, column * 50, 50, 50, whitePen, whiteBrush);
            }
            int figure = chessboard->getFigureOnPos(row, column);

            if (figure == Dama::Chessboard::DAMA_BLACK) {
                    QGraphicsItem * item = scene->addPixmap(dama_black);
                    item->setPos(column * 50, row * 50);
            }
            else if (figure == Dama::Chessboard::DAMA_WHITE) {
                QGraphicsItem * item = scene->addPixmap(dama_white);
                item->setPos(column * 50, row * 50);
            }
            else if (figure == Dama::Chessboard::PANAK_BLACK) {
                QGraphicsItem * item = scene->addPixmap(panak_black);
                item->setPos(column * 50, row * 50);
            }
            else if (figure == Dama::Chessboard::PANAK_WHITE) {
                QGraphicsItem * item = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap(panak_white));
                item->setPos(column * 50, row * 50);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGraphicsItem has a function called setZValue to set the stacking order of items where the higher valued item will be draw on top. By default, all items will be set to zero. If the items are in the correct position in the scene, set the z value of the figures to a higher value than the rects.